# Excel - Combine multiple columns into one column 3

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

What is the formula that we can use in Microsoft Excel to get the result of the value summation from string column A and string Column C if they are the same?  Column B and Column  D are both the number that assign to its respective column which is Column A and Column C. For example “orange” holds the value 6 (in Column B) for Column A while in Column C “orange” hold the value 2 (in column D).Final results should show the summation of 6+2=8 (in Column F) for string ‘Orange’ (Column E).

Thank you
Lupe

Comment: This seems more like a superuser.com question

Comment: The question would be easier to understand with a picture or diagram.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this table:

```
A       B   C       D
orange  1   orange  6
apple   2   apple   7
grapes  3   carrot  8
carrot  4   melon   9
```

And you want to search in column C for each of the A column values, you should use this in column E: (for E2, and drag down)

```
=IFERROR($B2+VLOOKUP($A2,$C$2:$D$5,2,FALSE), 0)
```

make sure to change $C$2:$D$5 to your range (in both places).

```
A       B   C       D   E
orange  1   orange  6   7
apple   2   apple   7   9
grapes  3   carrot  8   0
carrot  4   melon   9   12
```

Comment: I'd suggest one simplification to this using IFERROR(): `=IFERROR($B2+VLOOKUP($A2,$C$2:$D$5,2,FALSE), 0)` IFERROR() returns the value tested if it is not an error, otherwise it returns the second parameter. This makes Excel functions much shorter.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, thanks for this, changed the answer with this. I guess it's just an old habit of mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both AgentMike and Alexandre P. Levasseur for your help. The formula is working now. Appreciate the effort so much!!!

Comment: Hi, what if we add a new (column F and column H) where the data look quit similar as in Column  A, and add new(Column G and I) with value as similar as Column B, how the formula will look like if we add more column for string and value?

Comment: Well, if F and H are additional 'name' columns, and G and I are additional values, I would do something like this `=IFERROR($B2+VLOOKUP($A2,$C$2:$D$5,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($A2,$F$2:$G$5,2,FALSE)+VLOOKUP($A2,$H$2:$I$5,2,FALSE), 0)` (Assuming that if any of the values is missing, the sum is 0). You could also use the same range for all of the `VLOOKUP`, and change the required column number.